# Will App id be deleted when leave the developer team?

Tags: xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, app-id, bundle-identifier

My Personal Apple id has been added as a user to a developer team. And so far I created bundle Identifier and App Ids by using "Automatically manage signin" in xcode. Now I want to leave this team. I want to know will those App ID,s Provisioning profiles, bundle identifiers and certificates which were automatically created by Xcode still remaining under my previous team.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. All of that information belongs to the *team*. It has no association with you *personally*.

Comment: Is there any way to delete them? I mean automatically created things by the Xcode?

Comment: If you have a sufficiently high role, you can go to the Member Center in your web browser and delete them. But copies might still exist on someone else's computer...

Comment: But I cannot see those automatically created provisioning profiles on developer portal. But I know Xcode created. How to find those hidden App IDs and provisioning profiles?

Comment: Perhaps your role is not high enough to see them. In that case, there's probably nothing you can do. I don't see what the issue is here; these are not harmful objects.

Comment: Thanks. Because I wanted to make sure whether my xcode didnt create any provisioning profile under my previous company Team. They havent removed me from that team and When I add my personal ID to Xcode it shows that previous company Team as well